# Copying a TFS 2010 instance using Team Project Collection Cloning?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We are looking to create a test TFS 2010 server based on our live instance.
One method which has been suggested is to clone the Team Project Collection (TPC) onto to another server - as detailed [in this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796649/team-foundation-server-cloning-a-collections-project-into-a-new-collection/4918289#4918289) but I think there are a few additional steps?

In order to get the cloned TPC's GUID reset, I take it we would have to first reattach the cloned TPC in the admin console on the original server ***then*** detach, move and reattach on to test Server/TFS instance.

We are not running Sharepoint/WSS but would there be additional config work required on the test server with SSRS - in order for new projects to be created against the cloned TPC? 
Are there additional using diffrent AD accounts for services or can all of that be resolved within the admin console on the new server?

Both servers will running on VMWare and on the same domain but different AD accounts would be used on the two servers to help prevent any unwanted interactions between the TFS instances.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommended convert your TFS to virtual environment P2V using SCVMM, see this article,

http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/converting-my-physical-domain-controller-to-a-virtual-machine-p2v/

Comment: Hi Mohamed, 

Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid this is not an option for us at the moment. The live instance is running under VMWare, which is also where the Test server will be located. We don't have SCVMM in house nor any plans to implement. Also I'm not clear how this will help us with cloning TFS?