# cannot start TFS collection after cloning

Tags: tfs

I was trying to clone a team project collection, to create a test/backup collection. I found a post on here [Team Foundation Server: Cloning a Collection's Project into a new Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796649/team-foundation-server-cloning-a-collections-project-into-a-new-collection)

but after doing all the steps mentioned, I was not able to start the new collection, cause it keeps complaining that team projects are duplicated within both team project collections. Any ideas as to how i can start up the new collection, aside from deleting all the projects or stopping the other collection.

Comment: Are you sure you detached original team project collection?

Comment: yes i did detach the original, before i took the backup and then i reattached it. After that i restored the backup under a different name and attached that under a new collection name. Collection got creating and DB atached, but the collection is offline. If i try to get it online, it complains about dupicate team projects between the origianl collection and new collection.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to delete team projects from either the original or the duplicated collection such that each team project appears in only one collection - either original or new one, it doesn't matter.  Each team project has a GUID that identifies it, and there can only be one instance of each team project per server.

On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936158.aspx, it's called out in the Delete Projects on the Split Collections section.