# TFS 2010 Copy Project (including history) severance

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, copy, project

I want to copy an entire TFS project to another project, e.g. MyProj to MyProjSev. Then I want to rollback MyProjSev to a changeset that corresponds to when the client stopped paying.  Then I will make MyProjSev available, including the history of the source files, to the client for a period of time as part of the severance agreement.  The access/security aspect I know.  I can easily make a branch, but if the client views the branch from a TFS Explorer Client, then the history is not available.  There are a couple of approaches that involve cloning the entire collection, and lacking an answer to this question here, I will use one of them.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4918289/553593  [TFS admin detach the collection, back up SQL Server database, TFS admin attach collection, SQL Server restore database to new database name, then TFS admin attach the restored collection]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee349263(v=vs.100).aspx [Collection command with /clone]

**New Information**  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe TFS Integration Tools was what finally worked for me.  This 2012 release is a very nice product. It was easy to do a TFS to TFS transfer from my MyProj to the new MyProjSev that I created for client to access. Upon completion I simply did some rollbacks and set the security in the new project. It would have been easier if in TFS 2010 one can rename projects (can do in TFS 2012) Neither the TFSConfig Collection /clone nor the procedure described in MS Docs for Splitting a Team Projects Collection will work for this task. The issue is that even though one ends up with two collections, their projects have the same names, and that is not allowed (and in TFS 2010 you cannot rename projects).

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to clone the collection as you suggested.

Comment: It turned the neither the clone, nor the recipe in the link (which resembles MS docs on Splitting a Team Projects Collection), worked. What did work was a TFS to TFS migration using http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe  TFS  Integration Tools

Comment: I don't understand why the projects having the same name is an issue if they are in different collections.  You have ColA\Foo and ColB\Foo.  You roll back ColB\Foo and give the client access to that, and keep ColA\Foo private with the latest code that only you have access to.

Comment: I worked through ColA\Foo and ColB\Foo in the TFS 2010 Admin Console; could not **simultaneously** _attach and start_ both collections; TFS emitted error message: not allowed.  I don't know why it's the case, it just is.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because the GUIDs are the same for both Team Projects, which breaks everything if you bring them both online.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question as described in **New Information** above in the text of the question. Note all this is specific to TFS 2010.